# db.QueryRow() returning the wrong number of arguments

Tags: postgresql, go, libpq

I have a file called `user.go`, the function `GetUserByUsernameOrEmail` returns the user model and an error. It grabs this user information from the database.

My goal is to get all parameters I `SELECT` of the user, but it returns one fewer than it should.

This is for a REST API, however the model itself is really the problem. The user has fields `user_id` uuid, `user_username` string, `user_email` string, `user_hash` string, `user_salt` string, `user_verified` bool, `user_admin` bool, `user_email_verified` bool.

I haven't tried much as I'm at a loss for steps to continue. To debug, however, I created 8 test variables `test, test2...test8`. I print all 8 variables (for more on this, see below).

```golang
    var test string
    var test2 string
    var test3 string
    var test4 string
    var test5 string
    var test6 string
    var test7 string
    var test8 string

    err = db.QueryRow(`
        SELECT 
            user_id, 
            user_username, 
            user_email, 
            user_hash,
            user_salt
            user_verified,
            user_admin,
            user_email_verified 
        FROM users
        WHERE user_`+field+`= $1
    `, value).Scan(&test, &test2, &test3, &test4, &test5, &test6, &test7, &test8)
```

**Expected**: I scan the 8 fields to my 8 variables, and go on with my day.
**Actual**: `2019/11/10 10:36:42 sql: expected 7 destination arguments in Scan, not 8`

**Some other things to note**
I did scan it to 7 variables to test, and got this when logging the 7 variables:

```
5e5d2f4a-1f5b-418d-a262-a63c719a3ea4 test test@[domain].com [hash] [salt] false false
```

Comment: Can you update the code in your question to be a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? As it is, there's no obvious error in your code, so no way really to help.

Comment: You're missing a comma in the select between `user_salt` and `user_verified`, that is the same thing as writing `user_salt AS user_verified`, i.e. you're selecting only `user_salt` and aliasing it as `user_verified` and skipping the actual `user_verified` column.

Comment: @mkopriva Oh my goodness! You're right. I'm sorry, it's been such a long night. Didn't know about that functionality though, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops - I missed a commma between `user_salt` and `user_verified`. Thanks [mkopriva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965900/mkopriva) for the help.